# How to make dispatchTouchEvent more flexible? (i can't move the map)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I'm using this code to get coordinations of point which I tap on with google maps view in adroid.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{   
    if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
            (int) event.getX(),
            (int) event.getY());
            // send the intent from here to your next activity with the GeoPoint coords.
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }                      
    return false;
}
```

It works fine, every time I touch map it shows me exact coordinates - but now I can't scroll through my map, because everything I get is coords when I try to "catch" the map and scroll to side.

How to fix it?

I have idea, that maybe when I tap two times it gets me coordinates, but I want to be able to "catch" the map and scroll it away.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to add a button to your mapview that switchs between two different behaviours. Whewn button is pressed the coordinates would be shown, when released the map would move.

You would just need to test button status in your "dispatchTouchEvent" method.

good luck.